# how to load huge xml into a list on starting the server in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a big xml of around 10 lakh rows.I want to load the xml data into an array on starting the server and keep that list with me through the entire user session through the website.Like we do in java,keeping the arraylist in servlet context.How can we put a big xml data into a collection on server startup to increase the performance of website in PHP.
Please guide n this.....

Answer (score 0):

Loading huge XML into the list is really bad idea for me.

Instead of that you can keep the records into the database table and create the proper index on that table will help you in the performance. If you want to do any aggregation you can use summary tables will help you to increase the performance.

I hope you don't need the entire XML you always required for one or two records from that. I suggest to playing with the database is the best choice.

PHP will reach memory exhaustion very quickly if we load huge content.

Comment: k.if i want to load these 10 lakh records in xml in database on application start.so that my application perform well,How can i do that on server startup in PHP?

Comment: why you need that much load that much big.. try with limit based approach. no one is interested to see 10 lakh record at a time. use limit and load on demand.. Play with scroll ajax functionality load it based on demand.. Please update your complete functionality what you'll do with 10 lakh data this may gives more clarity

Comment: But basically my approach is like i will load my xml in to database or a list first on start of server.Then what ever user selects i have to search through that list and give the total result,and then load it by ajax.In this approach,i dont know how to load the data into database at the start of server?

Comment: As of understanding you need to get input from the user then you need list the data. Hence create a input box ask user to type there and request with database on indexed column display the required result. You can play with limit based selection no need to load at the time of server startup. If you want to load minimum content use APC cache will help you further

Comment: But Before validating user response with database,u need to have database content i.e. xml loaded in db,so that when user clicks on something ,it does not have to insert the fresh xml in database at that time,or You are having some different approach sir????

Comment: Each click if we need to insert/modify 10 lakh record then it's really bad approach. But if we need insert/modify 1-10 records only in that database then this is the best approach. you need to load all the XML content into the database before starting to process its default one. I am handling 5 crore records in database it's working good also the database is increasing every week 6 lakh records. But the database is giving response less than 1 second whatever i am executing in that

Comment: I think your approach is good,but what i have to do is,when user clicks on something,it has to validate in database(i.e. with xml) for that selection by user and then it has to give some n number of records.Will this approach told by you be beneficial to me in keeping the loading time upto 1 second????

Comment: I think what Sundar is trying to say is that you should use a database and not an XML file, even if you data is in an XML file to start with. You should load this XML file into the database *once*, when you set up your application, not when the user session or the server start. Getting the records you need from the database would take miliseconds (1/1000th of a second). You need to learn some basic database operation. I'd suggest you start with http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: I am asking about how to load data when you set up your application only..please tell me that part...

Comment: You need to read a lot. I cannot give you a programming course here in the comments. You should start reading http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp. By your current level of knowledge it looks like this is too big a task for you, either with XML or a database. I might be wrong, though.